# How do you randomly take an element from an array and insert it to another for later use in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example `int new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`, I'd like to take 4 of them randomly then insert them to another array for later use.

Dumb question, but does this also need generators? The elements are already there so I don't see any use for generators here...

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: what are 'generators'?

Comment: If you want to take them randomly then you need to get random numbers to determine positions from where to take them

Comment: 1) Take 4 random indices. 2) Create an array with size 4. 3) Copy the 4 numbers to second array 4) Profit

Comment: hi there steve. what have you tried? please show us you made a reasonable attempt to get a random number through your code. And... generator? what are you referring to? Did you mean a constructor? atomic types such as `int` dont have constructors.

Comment: @vikingsteve with *atomic* i think you refer to `primitives` right?

Comment: @Lino correct, thx for clarifying

Comment: @vikingsteve okay, thought i missed something about `int` being magically concurrent :)

Comment: @Lino not in this universe at least... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To randomly select and move elements from one array to another in Java, you can use the Random class to generate a random index within the range of the original array, and then use that index to access and remove the element from the original array and add it to the new array.

Here's an example code snippet that randomly selects four elements from the original array and inserts them into a new array called selected:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] original = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] selected = new int[4];
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(original.length);
      selected[i] = original[randomIndex];
      original[randomIndex] = original[original.length - 1];
      original = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selected));
  }
}
```

Regarding your question about generators, you don't need to use any explicit generator in this code. The Random class takes care of generating the random numbers for us.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet should do the trick:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

public int[] getRandom4( int[] input ){
    final int[] output = new int[4];
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        output[i] = input[RANDOM.nextInt(input.length)];
    }
    return output;
}
```

**Note:** I prefer the `Random` instance to be static, but if you dislike that. Then just move it inside the method

Answer (score 0):

You can but the elements inside `ArrayList` instead of simple `array`

and then shuffle the elements using`Collections.shuffle(list)`

and then take first three or four elements or whatever you wants.